# How to use multiple ("named"?) routes at same time in a react app?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want my react app to be build like this

[image]

On the blue left side, I have some menu buttons `List A` and `List B` that I can use to switch between the underlying lists (the blue box with the items). The list items can be clicked to view their details.
On the green right side, I want a details view to be displayed of one of the clicked blue items.

When I switch between lists on the left side, I want the details view to be *unchanged* and vice versa.

So for the upper image I would need to have to routes that are active simultaneously. Something like this:

```
http://myapp.com?route=/list_a&route=/details/a3
```

My app is build with React and I currently am using react-router.

Is  it possible to realize something like this with react-router? Or do I need to implement this kind of routing by my own?

All I could manage is to either switch between lists OR between item details, because the used `<Route .../>` elements always match the a precise pattern.

Comment: Have you read the react router docs.

Comment: You mean these docs: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/? Sure. Do you want to point out a particular section? I at least could not find anything about parallel / "named" routes in the latest versions.

Comment: You should look at their page, it's got the master detail page look you want to implement.

Comment: Please read my question carefully. I explicitly want two separate, parallel active routes. Given the example above, clicking the "List B" button would deactivate the details view of A3 when I just would use master-detail pattern. This is not what I want.

Comment: @MichaelHilus did you ever find a solution to this? I am dealing with an almost identical problem right now and am having trouble finding any resources on it.

Comment: @SirBeastalot We finally implemented an own routing mechanism that handles uri's in the form of `https://localhost/?list=listA&details=a3`. I cannot share the code because of company restrictions.But it was not too hard: there are basically some `<Route />` components, that listen to `location` changes and conditionally render their childs. The hardest part was string parsing.